# Can this code be done shortened and/or be more efficient?

Tags: java, android

My current code:

```
TextView question; 
private int qType = -1;  
private int asked = 0;

private void QBegin() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    Random random = new Random();
    int qType = random.nextInt(5);
    switch(qType){
    case 0:
        question.setText("Question 1");
        break;
    case 1:
        question.setText("Q2");
        break;
    case 2:
        question.setText("Q3");
        break;
    case 3:
        question.setText("Q4");
        break;
    case 4:
        question.setText("Q5");
        break;
    }
    asked++;

    //intList.add(qType);
    getAnswers(qType);
    /*if(intList.contains(qType) && asked <= 5){
        QBegin();
    } else {
        answerCounter.setText("Congratulations!!! Your score : "+correct);
    }*/
}

private int answer;

private void getAnswers(int Type) {
    Random random = new Random();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(Type){
    case 1:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");
            answer2.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer3.setText("малая производительность");
            answer4.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer2.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");
            answer3.setText("малая производительность");
            answer4.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer2.setText("малая производительность");
            answer3.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");
            answer4.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("сложность в управлении");
            answer2.setText("малая производительность");
            answer3.setText("нету выделения энергии непосредственно в загрузке");
            answer4.setText("относительно низкая температура шлаков");

        }

        break;

    case 2:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");
            answer2.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer3.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer4.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer2.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");
            answer3.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer4.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer2.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer3.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");
            answer4.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("открытые - плавка на воздухе");
            answer2.setText("вакуумные - плавка в вакууме");
            answer3.setText("компрессорные - плавка под избыточным давлением");
            answer4.setText("закрытые - плавка под слоем шихты");

        }

        break;

    case 3:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");
            answer2.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer3.setText("в которой тепло не передаеться тепло излучением");
            answer4.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer2.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");
            answer3.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer4.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer2.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer3.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");
            answer4.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer2.setText("в которой используеться активное сопротивление в качестве шихты");
            answer3.setText("в которой которая делиться на компрессорную печь с активным сопротивлением");
            answer4.setText("в которой тепло выделяется в результате прохождения тока через проводники с активным сопротивлением");

        }

        break;

    case 4:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("Correct");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Correct");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Correct");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Correct");

        }

        break;

    case 5:
        if(random.nextInt(4) == 0){
            answer = 1;
            answer1.setText("Correct");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 1){
            answer = 2;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Correct");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 2){
            answer = 3;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Correct");
            answer4.setText("Incorrect");
        } else if (random.nextInt(4) == 3){
            answer = 4;
            answer1.setText("Inorrect");
            answer2.setText("Incorrect");
            answer3.setText("Incorrect");
            answer4.setText("Correct");

        }

        break;

    }
}
```

- Basicly, I made a simple app for my android, where it picks a random question for you, and picks specific answers, only 1 of the answers is correct, other's aren't.

  - Also after editing QBegin method, it started to give me questions but with wrong answers!!! Help me with that aswell, please.

P.S.
Ignore the odd language!

Comment: This question would be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: THe first thing that comes to mind is, that you call `random.nextInt()` in every `if`. so everytime a new Random number gets generated and your ifs are not exhaustive

Comment: Is there a difference between `Incorrect` and `Inorrect`?

Comment: The only difference is that they have different text written on them, but they both are incorrect answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code can be made shorter and nicer.

```
class QuestionWithAnswers {

  private final String question;
  private final String[] answers;
  private final String correctAnswer;

  public QuestionWithAnswers( //
      String question, //
      String correctAnswer, //
      String... wrongAnswers, //
      Random rnd //
  ) {
    int n = wrongAnswers.length;
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = Arrays.copy(wrongAnswers, n + 1);
    this.answers[n] = correctAnswer;
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(this.answers), rnd);
  }

  public boolean isCorrect(String answer) {
    return answer.equals(correctAnswer);
  }

  public String[] getAnswers() {
    return answers.clone();
  }

}
```

Based on this data structure, it should be pretty simple to make the code shorter, since you don't need to shuffle the answers yourself.